# Did Concorde's sonic booms affect other air traffic?

Tags: supersonic, concorde

Given that Concorde's sonic boom reached the ground, it also must have reached other nearby air traffic.

How was this dealt with? I imagine passengers would not welcome hearing a loud boom during their flight.

Comment: http://acousticstoday.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Concorde-Booms-and-the-Mysterious-East-Coast-Noises-Peter-H-Rogers-and-Domenic-J.-Maglieri.pdf

Comment: This doesn't answer your question as written, but it is worth noting that due to the high take-off and landing speeds required by that wing, they had to have much wider separation of traffic around Concorde flights than for Heavies.  It would generate strong vortex winds.

Comment: Good point. Obviously there'd be a natural separation during the flight as well, since Concorde was significantly higher than any other traffic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this airliners.net post](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=733201#p10587623) (written when the Concorde was *still flying*, BTW), the Concorde's sonic booms could often be heard from other aircraft, but never posed problems for said other aircraft:

> Sometimes, to the South of Ireland, during the early part of the acceleration on a Westbound flight, Concorde flies over subsonic traffic that is arriving from the USA and cruising around FL370-FL410. If close to this traffic, by which I mean 10-15 miles, then ATC will often warn them that they may be "boomed" as the shock waves pass over them.
>
> From the reports I've heard from some of these crew, this can vary from nothing to a clearly audible double boom, but nothing to cause any concern or alarm.